# The window closes unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x

I just learned python and created my first program to solve a problem(from projecteuler.com).
here is the code

```
def multiples_of_3_5(limit):
 sum = 0
 for i in range(limit):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        sum += i
 return sum

print("Please input a number")
num = input()
print(multiples_of_3_5(num))
input()
```

i saved this as project1.py, but opening the .py file opens a CMD windown asking "please input a number". But soon as I input a number the window closes. tried addint input() at the end but still this happens

Comment: open a command line and execute the script in it. Then you can see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it from a command line. Then instead of `num=input()` use `num=int(input)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try import time and time.sleep(0.01) or int(). I'm new to Python too, so this might not work!

Comment: im not yet familiar with the time module but I will try this too thanks for the help :)